# Eclipse Photon: Test Suite results in "Np test found with test runner 'JUnit 5"." error message

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

In Eclipse Photon I have a project based on Java 1.8 with multiple Junit 5 Unit Tests.   The individual unit tests work well and now I'm looking to generate a Junit Test Suite.

Based on the JUnit5 User Guide I have created a AllTest.java file that has the following code:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("Test Suite")
@SelectPackages("com")
public class AllTests
{

}
```

When I execute these Java file I get the following error message:

[Screen Shot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1WT2.jpg)

I've also tried the @SelectClasses and have run into the same issue.

Has anyone else seen this issue or know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) is a JUnit4 annotation, so while executing the test we have to select RunConfiguration and select Junit 4 is the drop down instead of Junit 5. This will run the tests.